# Check to ping google from host in check_mk using WATO

Tags: monitoring, check-mk

I'm new to check_mk and got it installed using OMD (last daily version). I'm trying to create a check so my hosts ping google to see if their network connection to the internet is working. I thought something so basic could be available using wato but I can't find it and as I have defined all using WATO now I'm not sure how to configure this manually.

I tried to add in the `/omd/sites/mysite/etc/check_mk/main.mk` the following

```
define command {
         command_name    check_tcp_http
         command_line    $USER1$/check_tcp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 80
}

legacy_checks = [
   ( ( "check_tcp_http!www.google.com", "HTTP Service", True), [ "httpd" ], ALL_HOSTS ),
]
```

but get an error when check_mk tries to read the main.mk

Any idea how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: It's not possible to define a check like this from the server side since the agent is not designed to ever accept external input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get it working by using local checks. I created a script on my hosts in the /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local that the check_mk reads and pass the output to the Check_mk server

```
#!/bin/bash

host=8.8.8.8
if ping -c 1 $host &> /dev/nul
then
  status=0
  statustxt=OK
else
    status=2
    statustxt=CRITICAL
fi
echo "$status ping_$host varname=2;crit $statustxt"
```

Comment: You should just make one addition and suppress error messages from the script as they could break the local checks section, badly.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Errors from ping wil be printed prior to the echo. When that happens, your local check section of the agent output will go to hell

Comment: Doesn't `&>` redirect all output, including errors?  But the problem I see is that `/dev/nul` probably won't exist and should be `/dev/null` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MRPE with nagios-plugins-icmp：

For example in centos agent:

```
# yum -y install epel-release
# yum -y install nagios-plugins-icmp

# cat /etc/check_mk/mrpe.cfg
  PingDNS8888 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_icmp 8.8.8.8
```

Path in x86_64 maybe

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_icmp
```

That's all.